# Where are the actions stored that the Contacts.app can apply on telephone numbers?

Tags: macos, contacts, script

When I click on a telephone number in Contacts.app (or more precise: on the word left of it) I get to see the following menu:

[image]

Where does Contact.app store these actions? I couldn't find anything in the `/Library/Scripts` or `~/Library/Scripts` folder.
I want to know this as I think the `Send SMS with Bluetooth` is not natively present and I want to copy this action over to a new install I'm going to do.

Comment: Did you create the Send SMS via Bluetooth yourself?

Comment: I sort of forgot... It's quite an old system. I guess so. It might be some plugin, but I can't find a plugin that bears that name.

Comment: I think it's installed in the same folder as the Skype actions, so if I find those, I'll probably find the Bluetooth SMS as well. So where does Skype install these actions?

Comment: No, don't think so. It involves clicking a bluetooth in the toolbar, but I have none (I don't even have a toolbar as Contacts on ML doesn't have one). I have a Nokia 6300 phone if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the install directory. Apparently it was the action posted [here](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20091002073002415). The action is installed in `~/Library/Address Book Plug-Ins`